# Web browser is playing the video clips very quickly

Tags: linux, ubuntu, google-chrome, video, browser

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and have noticed that after restart there is no problem with watching  video clips in the net, but after some time, when I try to open a video click (for example from YouTube) it runs too quickly and strange noises appears.

The problem is only with Chromium browsers which is version 22.0.1229.94 and what is really strange is that I have not met the same problem using Firefox. That's what I suppose this is problem with the browsers itself, not my hardware and drivers.

Could anyone advice what to do?

Comment: what flash plugin do you have installed?

Comment: I have installed adobe flash because it was required,but as far as i have known, YouTube is using HTML5 video if your browser supports it and I am with the latest version of chrome for Ubuntu.

Comment: This can actually depend on the video, as some cannot be re-encoded for HTML 5 and will be using flash (I think this is more a licensing than tech problem). Right clicking the video widget should tell you what is being used.

Comment: I have adobe flash version - 11.4.31.110